# Convert MathAtan2 angle to degrees

Tags: java, libgdx, mathematics

I use an angle to set the velocity (or direction if you prefer) of my sprite, however, I want the sprite to be heading in the same angle as I'm moving, rotating according to that angle.

How I set angle and velocity:

```
angle = (float)Math.atan2(0 - pos.y, 220 - pos.x); //using bottom mid of screen as destination for testing

//in update
pos.x += 200 * Math.cos(angle) * delta;
pos.y += 200 * Math.sin(angle) * delta;
sprite.setPosition(pos.x, pos.y);

//in render
sprite.draw(batch);
```

is there any way to use this value in LibGdx's "sprite.rotate()" function? I can't do "sprite.rotate(angle)". Can I do this some other way? Can I convert my angle-value somehow to degrees? I'm stuck.

I tried

```
sprite.rotate((float)Math.toDegrees(angle));
```

but that gave rly weird results, the following image is moving **down** and to the **right**

[image: img]

Comment: "rly wierd results" how? That says nothing about the result you got.

Comment: Hmm, hard to explain, Ill post an image

Comment: Is it the same as in http://stackoverflow.com/q/27345132/731620 ?

Comment: I tried using `sprite.setRotation((MathUtils.radiansToDegrees * angle));` but getting wrong result still. I dont actually rotate it in update, since it never changes direction I set the angle in the constructor, after the position has been set.

Comment: @ratchetfreak added an image

Comment: Then it sounds like 0 rotation of the sprite doesn't match what direction it's going (that's positive x). Then just add an offset to it to correct.

Answer (score 1):

`rotate` takes I believe a `relative` rotation while angle is an `absolute` rotation. In other words take the difference between the current angle and the wanted angle and pass that to rotate.

Or pass just the angle into `setRotation`.